# Run gem from local source code

Tags: ruby

I am currently working on developing a gem and I would like to be able to run that gem from command line and point it to my local source. Previously I've done this in rails by specifying the path in the gem file but now I would like to run the gem on a non rails app. So I would like to know how to call the gem from command line and specify that I want to use the source code in a certain directory.

For example can I cd into the directory that I want to run it on and do something like: `ruby my_gem --path=~/code/mygem`

Also do I have to build them gem or can I run it from source without building it?

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. You are trying run your gem by specifying path. You can use irb to (not sure as requirement is not clear). Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Yes sorry, I would like execute a development version of the gem (rubycritic) from the root directory of another  ruby project. So I would like to cd into `~/code/another_ruby_project` and then run my version of rubycritic on the code in that directory. For reference: https://github.com/whitesmith/rubycritic

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the root directory of your gem, try this to execute `lib/MyGem.rb`:

```
ruby -Ilib lib/MyGem.rb
```

or test your gem interactive:

```
irb -Ilib
> require 'mygem'
true
```